# Load Braintree ClientToken asynchronously in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, braintree-rails

I am currently using `gon` gem to load the client_token in braintree.

Below shows the controller methods:

```
def new
    @rental_info = display_rental_info(params[:rental_request_new_form])
    @product = Product.find(params[:rental_request_new_form][:product_id])
    gon.client_token = generate_client_token
end

private

def generate_client_token
    Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id)
end
```

Soon enough, I realised the potential problem of this way. If the connection to Braintree is slow, it will just hold the request and block all other requests. Sometimes (in a rare probability), it will take 6-10s to load the request. And one time it actually result in `Net::OpenTimeout - execution expired` error after waiting for 60seconds..

I wonder what is a good way to come around this and prevent it from blocking other requests

Comment: You can make an Asynchronous call to generate token.

Comment: on the frontend side in ajvascript?

Comment: in rails : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124360/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-asynchronous-jobs-in-a-rails-application

Comment: i doubt if i can use resque or sidekiq for it because the output of gon is needed when generating the frontend

Comment: Then you can't do it asynchronously - a better question is why is Braintree taking so long?

Answer (score 1):

I work at Braintree. The response times that you are seeing for our ClientToken.generate endpoint are unusual for our production environment, but may be experienced in our sandbox environment. I would suggest that you reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) to further diagnose this issue.

Further, calling out to Braintree in a single request should not block other requests to your web server. Web servers handle multiple requests concurrently. If you attempted to make the call to ClientToken.generate asynchronously, it would allow you to do other server side processing for this request while the Braintree token is being received, but I would weigh the benefits of parallelizing the processing for a single request before committing to the additional complexity.